# PostgreSQL: updating two columns is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

The PostgreSQL version is 9.2. The data table contains more than 100 million rows. It has four columns: a, b, c and d. Column a and b are character varying type. I want to add two columns: e=least(a,b) and f=greatest(a,b). The code is

```
UPDATE table
SET e=least(a,b),f=greatest(a,b)
```

But after 36 hours passed, it is still running. Why is the update so slow?

---

Updated:
When I use 'select into' method, it only used 40 minutes to complete!
Now I need to learn more about the implementation way of PostgreSQL functions.

Comment: Update your question with your table's structure (scrubbed) using `psql`'s `\d+ my_table`. Also if possible include the output from an `EXPLAIN UPDATE my_table SET e=LEAST(a,b), f=GREATEST(a,b);`

Comment: The query plan is '"  ->  Seq Scan on **tablename** (cost=0.00..2718123.99 rows=148261349 width=86)"'.

Comment: 100M rows is alot, but not imposible. Have you checked for locks on the table? 36 hours is too much for this operation. My guess - it is wating for some other transaction to commit.

Comment: Anything in `pg_locks` with `granted` false? See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring . Your query will do a full table rewrite, generating a new version of every row, but 36h is still crazy.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is a locking issue.  What's probably happening is that the update is waiting on another update that is not committing.

The first thing to do is to look at the `pg_locks` view.  After that, you can try restarting PostgreSQL (when convenient) and re-running the update query.  You could also try adding NOWAIT to your update statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;  UPDATE table SET ...
```

This will cause exceptions rather than wait for locks to be released.

Comment: I can't find anything in the manual that there is a `NOWAIT` option for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You'd have to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` then `UPDATE` - and hope nobody inserted rows then took locks on them in the mean time, or do your `UPDATE` on the IDs you selected.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you edit your answer please? The `UPDATE mytable NOWAIT SET ...` is a bit confusing I think.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware stats? RAM? Disk speed? Those things help determine answers on open-ended questions like this.

Are e and f indexed?

Since you are updating the entire table, have you tried `INSERT INTO some_temp_table SELECT least(a,b) e, greatest(a,b) f FROM yourtable` instead? UPDATE operations are traditionally the slowest DML operation you can execute.

Comment: The RAM is 16 GB. The disk is 7200 RPM. e and f are not indexed. I have not tried the insert method yet. You know, 36 hours is so long that I expect the update may end at any minute.